# Python Selenium: Geting different results using driver.find_elements

Tags: python, selenium

I'm new to selenium. I have this situation and i don't know how to solve it:

- If i use direct link in `driver.get()` i can find and count elements w/o problems using:

  - `element.driver.find_elements_by_xpath();`
  - `print(len(element))`

I get correct printed result

- if I use home page instead in `driver.get()`:

  - locate search button;
  - send keys and submit;
  - `element.driver.find_elements_by_xpath();`
  - `print(len(element))`

Test is passed but `result is 0`. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: This is the timing problem, it is trying to count even before elements are loaded in DOM, I strongly suggest you to use WATIR(Wrapper of Ruby selenium binding) since you are a beginner, In WATIR all the waiting condition automatically be handled. It checks four conditions before it interact an element (exists? visible? enabled? writable?) So you don't have to do anything by yourself, If you use selenium bindings directly these checking will not be available for you. WATIR which is the wrapper around selenium gives these checks and also gives you the function which avoids writings xpath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wait after the action before you validate.  Web drivers provide "wait conditions" that you can use to validate you reached your desired checkpoint before performing other validation operations.

We are not talking about system waits, we are talking about wait conditions where the driver can poll the browser until a given condition is met.  There are many conditions and many options for these, and you will need them fairly universally to accomplish your goals.  That is why I'm not providing an example.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know about waits. In fact i was using a wrong wait condition and wasn't getting the results. Just now i used EC.presence_of_all_elements_located and I got my results!